# How to read files from Google drive through python when it says Google hasn’t verified this app?

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

I have created project and even i have client_secret.js file, when i try to run the program first time it asks to login, when I tried to login through gmail (which I have used to create project) it says

> "Google hasn’t verified this app"

Message, so for that i'm looking how to get out from this step.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

When you create an application Google developer console it is considered to be in development. Once your application has completed development and you are ready to go to production you will need to apply for [verification](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en).

To get around this while in development you should just click the continue button on the screen above. This will then allow you to login to your application while you are testing it.

Answer (score -1):

This is occuring because the application you created is not verified by google so you are not able to login in that you need to verify it by google suite and then you are able to login I also get that problem when i tried to create an browser for myself